# Should searching for "someIdentifier" match "someOtherIdentifier.someIdentifier"?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, search

I noticed today that searching for "someIdentifier" does not match "someId.someIdentifier".

Example: Searching for "[[webgl] bindFramebuffer](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bwebgl%5D%20bindFramebuffer)" produces [only five results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7S4jU.png), but searching for "[[webgl] gl.bindFramebuffer](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bwebgl%5D%20gl.bindFramebuffer)" produces ~182 results.

The issue is the `gl` part is user defined. Some people call it [`context`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bwebgl%5D%20context.texImage2D), some people call it [`ctx`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bwebgl%5D%20ctx.bindFramebuffer). Some people have it as a property of an object so it becomes [`this.gl`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bwebgl%5D%20this.gl.bindFramebuffer) or [`this.ctx`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bwebgl%5D%20this.ctx.bindFramebuffer)

Should Stack Overflow's search function handle this differently so that searching for "someId" matches "someOtherId.someId"?

Comment: While good suggestion, I don't see any value to implement as a feature-request. Search on SO is... nowhere as useful as any real search engine so fixing one tiny issue not going to make me use it.

Comment: I agree the system should do that by default. If of any help though, it seems [the search `*bindFramebuffer [webgl]`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=*bindFramebuffer+[webgl]) will return what you want.

Comment: I posted a related request on Meta Stack Exchange a while ago: [searching for “writing” should list results with “writing.se”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/330482/295232) – it also contains some information about *how* they should implement it.